Permission denied on simple podman curl container oneliner (CoreOS system)
On a relatively fresh and simple CoreOS system, trying to run the following command:
podman run --rm docker.io/curlimages/curl -v host.containers.internal:2040

Results in the following error:
{"msg":"exec container process `/entrypoint.sh`: Permission denied","level":"error","time":"2024-11-22T22:12:56.046889Z"}

To which I am at a complete loss. I've tried the following:

sudo setenforce 0 to disable SELinux temporarily, which did not change the error received.

Added the --userns=keep-id flag to the command, which also didn't change the results.


EG:
podman run --userns=keep-id --rm docker.io/curlimages/curl -v host.containers.internal:2040


For other more complex podman containers, I tried setting the :z flag for volume mounts to no avail.

There must be something I'm doing wrong on my system. The only abnormal part of my system is that I have podman and docker both installed on the same machine for compatibility reasons but my understanding is that this shouldn't be a conflict.

Extra information: For some reason, creating a new user works as expected. Perhaps there's a user configuration error?

Can you update the question to include a reproducible configuration? Just booting an instance of fedora-coreos-stable (or -next), starting a container that publishes a service on port 2040, and then running your curlimages/curl example works without any errors.

You can find my successful test here

Found the answer myself with some debugging.
Basically, there was a facl flag of some sort that was interfering with the permissions of newly created images which was resulting in some strange behaviour.
I was able to fix this by nuking my ~/.local/share/containers and starting fresh, while also making sure that all extended facl permissions were cleared by using setfacl -bR ~/.local. I think this was set erroneously by a user, but I would probably argue that user level facls probably shouldn't interfere with podman rootless behaviour.
